# How is work function for a metal in photoelectric effect just one single number?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I mean,there are so many electrons  at different positions on the surface of the metal,at different depths with different energies.
how is it possible that work function for all the electrons same?
is it the ''average''  energy needed for an electron 'just' to leave the surface?

Comment: FWIW, that's what I always took it to mean, just the surface layer.

Comment: @Acid Jazz :So you mean this is average energy needed?

Comment: The electrons are shared among their hosting atoms and they form energy bands (see [Electronic band structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure)). Now an energy level in the valence band is not localized around an atom, but it may be found around all the atoms. The electron occupying the energy level with highest affinity to leave the surface is also shared among all the atoms, so you will see the same electron (or energy level) across the surface. Also, when it gets kicked out, the level quickly gets filled with another electron.

Comment: @gox :That can be an ans,if you write an ans,I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Wiki has this, stressing minimum  rather than average, which does make more sense to me. As regards the surface aspect, if you are dealing with minimum energy, then I can't think of a "looser" place for electrons to be liberated from:

> In solid-state physics, the work function (sometimes spelled workfunction) is the minimum thermodynamic work (i.e. energy) needed to remove an electron from a solid to a point in the vacuum immediately outside the solid surface. Here "immediately" means that the final electron position is far from the surface on the atomic scale, but still too close to the solid to be influenced by ambient electric fields in the vacuum. The work function is not a characteristic of a bulk material, but rather a property of the surface of the material (depending on crystal face and contamination)

[Work function from Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function)

Comment: I did read that but that ''minimum'' is different for different electrons right?

Comment: Yep, but so is the work function for different metals, and their purity, for example, are we in practice dealing with a pure metal, or is it nearly always an oxide? In other words, the work function is, in reality, based on a compound of the metal unless you really clean it first.

Comment: For the classic experiment, it is always a pure metal, and in fact oxides such as sodium oxide do not show photoelectric activity at visible wavelengths (not surprising, since it is an insulator). The original experiments required considerable ingenuity to produce a clean surface in a vacuum tube.

Comment: Also minimum doesn't make sense if temperature is not specified. The Fermi-Dirac distribution depends on temperature, so varying temperature increase/decrease the gap between highest occupied band and vacuum level.